# How to customize a "MsgBox" control in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, msgbox

Is there a way to customize the [MsgBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) control in Visual Basic?

I use it quite often to alert users. However it never pops up on the screen; it just appears along the bottom task bar. It also always has a heading similar to "App_data_xxx". Can I improve this in any way?

My searches aren't throwing up much help.

For example:

```
' Queries user number and password against the database and returns user
Dim matchingusers = From u In db.Users
                    Where username = u.Email And password = u.Password
                    Select u

' Checks if a valid user was returned
If matchingusers.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Invalid user entered, try again")
Else
    SelectedDeveloper = 0
    ' Set the logged in user for use in the project
    GlobalVariables.LoggedInUser = matchingusers.First
```

Comment: For full customization just make a separate form, then make it visible when ever you want to alert the user...

Comment: MsgBox is the olden function, MessageBox is the newer one with more options.  But even MsgBox has a Title argument, hard to not discover that.  You are probably using it inappropriately if you feel a need to customize it.  Its in-your-face reporting is pretty grating to a user, only use it sparingly and only for grave problems.  Or you run the risk of the user routinely dismissing the box without reading it, missing the important ones.  Lots of lesser evils available in a GUI class library.

Comment: If you are using vb .net use MessageBox.  If that doesn't have what you want make your own form.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to show it

Comment: i have edited post to include some code.  When I try to use `MessageBox` I get "Cannot resolve Symbol MessageBox"

Comment: Call it `Messagebox.Show()`. Check here the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `MessageBox` function and its many variables. Here's an example of what it can do:

```
 MessageBox.Show("The Displayed text in the messagebox", _
         "the text displayed in the title bar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, _
             MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)
```

Or you can still use `MsgBox` and use its variables, though it gives you fewer options. Here's an example:

```
MsgBox("message text", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "title bar text")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a reference to the `MessageBox` class without specifying the `Method` you want to call. You cannot create an instance of `MessageBox` and therefore cannot pass a string as parameter to try and create one.

Use `MessageBox.Show(string messageText)` to display the `MessageBox` with the desired message.

As for your question, you should create your own `MessageBox` class. With this solution, you get all the options you want and can customize it completely. The call will be a little different :

```
//C#
var myCustomMessageBox = new CustomMessageBox();
myCustomMessageBox.ShowDialog();

//Vb
Dim myCustomMessageBox As New CustomMessageBox()
myCustomMessageBox.ShowDialog()
```

The [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) will be used to create the effect of a messagebox.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Basic 2008 I had a requirement for a message box that would only stay on for short times and that the time it was on to be variable. I also had the problem that when using extended screen that the msgbox showed up on the extended screen (which was a different form)  instead of on the main computer screen. To overcome these problems I created a custom Message Box using a panel on the form I had on the main screen.

To call the message panel DoMessage("The message", Seconds, Buttons to show 1 = Ok only 2 = Yes(ok) and No, 3 = Yes, No and Cancel. If seconds is 0 or not specified then the time to show the panel is set to a long time (10000 seconds) If Buttons to show is not specified it is set to Ok button only. If seconds and buttons are both specified, If no button is clicked the panel will just hide after the timeout.

The responses are 1 if Ok or Yes is clicked, 2 if No is clicked, 3 if Cancel is clicked
It is put into DoMsgResp so you see what is in it to handle the response.

Create the message panel when opening the form by calling MakeMsgPanel()

```
Dim MessagePanel As New Panel    'The panel 
Dim MessageLabel As New Label    'The message 
Dim MsgYes As New Button          'Yes or OK button
Dim MsgNo As New Button          'no button
Dim MsgCcl As New Button         'Cancel button
Dim Sleepsecs As Integer          'How long panel shows for 
Dim DoMsgResp As Integer         'response 1, 2 or 3 depending which button clicked
Private Sub MakeMsgPanel()
    Me.Controls.Add(MessagePanel)
    Me.MessagePanel.Controls.Add(MessageLabel)
    Me.MessagePanel.Controls.Add(MsgYes)
    Me.MessagePanel.Controls.Add(MsgNo)
    Me.MessagePanel.Controls.Add(MsgCcl)
    MessagePanel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Width / 2 - 200, Me.Height / 2 - 100)
    MessagePanel.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
    MessageLabel.BackColor = Color.PeachPuff
    MessagePanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    MessageLabel.Font = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)
    MessageLabel.AutoSize = True
    MessagePanel.AutoSize = True
    MessagePanel.AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly
    MessagePanel.Hide()
    MsgYes.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(205, 5)
    MsgNo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(115, 5)
    MsgCcl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(25, 5)
    MsgYes.Text = "Yes"
    MsgNo.Text = "No"
    MsgCcl.Text = "Cancel"
    AddHandler MsgYes.Click, AddressOf MsgYes_Click
    AddHandler MsgNo.Click, AddressOf MsgNo_Click
    AddHandler MsgCcl.Click, AddressOf MsgCcl_Click
End Sub


Private Sub MsgYes_Click()
    DoMsgResp = 1
    Sleepsecs = 0
End Sub


Private Sub MsgNo_Click()
    DoMsgResp = 2
    Sleepsecs = 0
End Sub
Private Sub MsgCcl_Click()
    DoMsgResp = 3
    Sleepsecs = 0
End Sub


  Private Sub DoMessage(ByVal Msg As String, Optional ByVal Secs As Integer = 0, _
           Optional ByVal Btns As Integer = 0)
    'Information messages that can be timed
    Dim TheHeight As Integer
    Dim TheWidth As Integer
    Dim Labelx As Integer
    Dim Labely As Integer
    DoMsgResp = 0
    MessageLabel.Text = Msg
    If MessageLabel.Height < 90 Then
        TheHeight = 100
        Labely = (100 - MessageLabel.Height) / 2
    Else
        TheHeight = MessageLabel.Height + 10
        Labely = 5
    End If
    If MessageLabel.Width < 140 Then
        TheWidth = 150
        Labelx = (150 - MessageLabel.Width) / 2
    Else
        TheWidth = MessageLabel.Width + 10
        Labelx = 5
    End If
    MessagePanel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(TheWidth, TheHeight)
    MessageLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Labelx, Labely)
    MessageLabel.Show()
    MessagePanel.Show()
    MessagePanel.BringToFront()
    MsgYes.BringToFront()
    MsgNo.BringToFront()
    MsgCcl.BringToFront()
    MessagePanel.Focus()
    If Btns = 0 Or Btns > 3 Then Btns = 1 'Make ok button if none specified or number too high
    If Btns = 1 Then
        MsgYes.Text = "Ok"
        MsgNo.Hide()
        MsgCcl.Hide()
    Else    'is 2 or 3 
        MsgYes.Text = "Yes"
        MsgNo.Show()
        If Btns = 2 Then MsgCcl.Hide() Else MsgCcl.Show()
    End If
    If Secs = 0 Then Secs = 10000 'make a long time
    If Secs > 0 Then
        Sleepsecs = Secs * 2
        Do Until Sleepsecs < 1
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            Application.DoEvents()
            Application.RaiseIdle(New System.EventArgs)
            Sleepsecs = Sleepsecs - 1
        Loop
    End If
    MessagePanel.Hide()
End Sub


 Private Sub ButtonTest_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonTest.Click
            DoMessage("This is To see what happens with my message" & vbCrLf & _
              "see if it works good", 0, 3)
    If DoMsgResp = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Ok was hit")
    End If
    If DoMsgResp = 2 Then
        MsgBox("No was hit")
    End If
    If DoMsgResp = 3 Then
        MsgBox("Cancel was hit")
    End If
End Sub
```